# Get file name from a directory by searching a string in pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, kettle

I am going to prepare a job that has fields such as Path(DIRECTORY) and FileName. These fields value will change for every row.

Objective of my task is, I need to check whether the FileName file exists in the directory. That I did with the "File Exists" step and checked whether file exists. Then I used the "Filter Rows" step and performed an operation if the file exists.

If the file is not present in the directory, I need to check for the other files that starts with the filename value.

Example: I have the file name as "sample.png", if the file does not exists in the directory I want to search for the files that starts with "sample..."(Eg: sample_1.png).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the approach to

1. fetch the list of files having `sample` key in the directory using wildcard expression `^sample.*` in the "**Get File Names**" (use a ktr)
2. Then use a filter row step to filter out the two path. `True path` will pass the data having the filename `sample.png` and the `False path` will pass on the files incase sample.png is not found.

A sample image of the ktr would be like

[image]

My idea is to read all the files first from the path and then filter out whatever files are required, instead of double checking the existance of the files.

*N.B. In the image above, path is the location of the image directory. Use your own folder path to get the correct result.*

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Rishu. But I have the the directory path in the field "path" but when declaring it in the File/Directory column, it gives me an error "Could not list the contents of "file:///home/Arun/Path" because it is not a folder." Any alternate ideas would be great.

Comment: @Arunraj have you tried passing the directory path as a parameter like ${path} where path=variable defined. In the example above i haven't used dynamic path parameter.... instead of path, just give the path of your image location if the path is not dynamic.

Comment: variable path is going to be dynamic, it will change for every rows, I thought of giving "path" in variable too, but dynamic value can't be set to a variable I guess.

Comment: @Arunraj yes dynamic path variables can be easily set up. Try reading this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/tag/copy-rows-to-result/). Hope this might help

Comment: I have tried as told in the blog, It runs the number of times it has to run, but when i use variable ${path}, it doesn't return any value (i.e) the directory path, it only returns ${path} as such. Do you know where i m going wrong.